# Glassfish - Different parameter value for the same application

Tags: java, glassfish

I have an application that requires some external parameters to do it's job.
At this moment I'm passing this parameters as JVM parameters and reading then through `System.getProperty()`.
Now, my application will be used by two different clients, and I want to pass different values depending on which client is accessing. I know that I can do that by creating two domains, but I would really like to have them using the same port, and app name. Ex:

```
http://client1.myurl.com:8080/app

http://client2.myurl.com:8080/app
```

I have already created two Virtual-Servers, but I can't find out how I can pass different parameters to the app depending on which Virtual-Server is calling it.

Comment: What do you mean with "how I can pass different parameters to the app"? If I understand your descriptions correctly you want to run one java application which covers two virtual servers. So there is only one app, and you have to distinguish dynamically at runtime which param set you should use. At startup you provide all needed param sets, maybe by qualifying the property name: "-Dproperty1.client1=value1, -Dproperty1.client2=value2, etc.". But as soon a third client comes into play this approach will turn out in a nightmare. Better parametrize the app through property files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Heri. The problem is, how to identify which client is accessing the application. One way that I can think is getting the URL. But I thought that since I can create the Virtual Servers, there was a way to pass to the application different parameters depending on which Virtual Server is used for the connection.

Comment: Why don't you answer my question and repeat instead the same wording which I do not understand?

Comment: Ok. So I have client1 and client2 using the same application. Client1 needs a set of parameters (Directory paths, database parameters, etc..). ClientB needs those same parameters but with different values. So, Problem 1: How do I know if is client1 or client2 that is accessing the application? Problem 2: How to define different values for the parameters if it's the same application?

Comment: On Tomcat, for example, I could create two Host entries in the server.xml with different appBase values and deploy the application on both hosts with a different properties file, as you suggested. But on Glassfish, as far as I could understand, there is no way to do that because the app is 'shared' by the Virtual Servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the problem.
I just needed to deploy the application twice with the same context-root but with a different name, binding each to a specific Virtual-Server.

In this scenario two applications folder will be created on domain/applications, allowing me to have two versions of the same app but with a different properties file.